# get a error when i tried request from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I develop a little db in mongoo
now in the front-end i tried to use my login route with axios.post request
but i dont know why i get a error
i also console.log the email and the password i send and they good

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './signIn.css'



function Signin() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [password, setPass] = useState("")

    const login = async () => {
        console.log(email, password)
        const res = await axios.post({
            // mathod: "POST",
            url: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login`,
            data: {
                email: email,
                password: password
            }
        })
        console.log(res)
    }

    return (
        <div className="pop-container">
            <div className="popup">
                <div className="content">
                    <h1>Sign in</h1>
                    <div className="input-field"><input placeholder="Email" className="validate" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} /></div>
                    <div className="input-field"><input placeholder="Password" className="validate" onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)} /></div>
                    <button onClick={(e) => login(e)} className="second-button">Sign in</button>
                    <p>Don't have an account? <a href="/signup.html">Sign Up</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Signin;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

the order i send the data in the body axios is coorect and also the url is correct

and i get this error

```js
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { stack: "AxiosError@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47353:18\nsettle@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47971:12\nonloadend@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:46711:66\nEventHandlerNonNull*dispatchXhrRequest@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:46724:7\nxhrAdapter@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:46666:10\ndispatchRequest@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47806:10\nrequest@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47270:77\nhttpMethod@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:47304:19\nwrap@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:48325:15\nlogin@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:239:69\nonClick@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:292:30\ncallCallback@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:14325:18\ninvokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:14369:20\ninvokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:14426:35\ninvokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:14440:29\nexecuteDispatch@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18584:46\nprocessDispatchQueueItemsInOrder@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18610:26\nprocessDispatchQueue@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18621:41\ndispatchEventsForPlugins@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18630:27\n./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem/<@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18790:16\nbatchedUpdates$1@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:33182:16\nbatchedUpdates@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:14173:16\ndispatchEventForPluginEventSystem@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18789:21\ndispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:16295:42\ndispatchEvent@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:16289:88\ndispatchDiscreteEvent@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:16266:22\nEventListener.handleEvent*addEventBubbleListener@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:16488:14\naddTrappedEventListener@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18712:33\nlistenToNativeEvent@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18656:30\n./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js/listenToAllSupportedEvents/<@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18667:34\nlistenToAllSupportedEvents@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:18662:25\ncreateRoot@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:35945:33\ncreateRoot$1@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:36291:14\n./node_modules/react-dom/client.js/exports.createRoot@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:36367:16\n./src/index.js@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:646:60\noptions.factory@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:50545:31\n__webpack_require__@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:49969:33\n@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:51191:56\n@http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:51193:12\n", message: "Request failed with status code 404", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, response: {…} }
​
code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
​
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
​​
adapter: function xhrAdapter(config)
​​
data: undefined
​​
env: Object { FormData: (), Blob: () }
​​
headers: Object { "Content-Type": null, Symbol("defaults"): {…} }
​​
maxBodyLength: -1
​​
maxContentLength: -1
​​
method: "post"
​​
timeout: 0
​​
transformRequest: Array [ transformRequest(data, headers)
 ]
​​
transformResponse: Array [ transformResponse(data)
 ]
​​
transitional: Object { silentJSONParsing: true, forcedJSONParsing: true, clarifyTimeoutError: false }
​​
url: Object { url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login", data: {…} }
​​​
data: Object { email: "test@gmail.com", password: "12345678" }
​​​
url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
validateStatus: function validateStatus(status)
​​
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
​​
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
message: "Request failed with status code 404"
​
name: "AxiosError"
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
response: Object { data: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /[object%20Object]</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n", status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", … }
```

please help me thnks

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login` is simply does not exist hence why you get 404 make sure you have correct url

Comment: why not? is the correct url and also i do a get request to another endpoing and it work fine

Comment: since axios says `message: "Request failed with status code 404"` that only and only means the URL was not found, since this is a react project I think you may have mistaken the ports make sure your URL port corresponds to your API port

Comment: also correct i use now in postmen also with the same url and it work

Comment: since I don't have access to your code I can only assume, so please make sure the url is correct, make sure the request type is POST request  from your api, make sure your PORT is correct. other than that we need a duplicate code so we can debug more so you can create a code snippet with a reproducible error

Comment: check all and all correct you need the code fromm back-end and front-end or just front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this and tell me the results?

```
const login = async () => {
    console.log(email, password);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/login`, {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: i think its work i dong get any error

Comment: works good! thenks men

Comment: No worries. In your code, it was just a syntax error.